# I am facing an issue in my fullstack program. When i am giving a command of npm start in terminal its not working

Tags: graphql, npm-start, react-fullstack

[If anyone know how to do it help me. in this program i used graphql and apollo-server-express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYtTS.jpg)

Expexting the solution to run graphql and apollo-server-express and error of npm start.I am facing problem of apollo-server-express ass well.If anyone know about this then give the solution please.

Comment: Please do not post photos of your code. Post your code as text in the question.

Comment: That being said, you are using an async function server.start() and you are not using await to wait for the response. This is happening in your server.js file. Read the error and the stack trace, they can be very helpful in isolating the issue.